# VMR9Allocator (DirectShow .NET + SlimDX)

Tags: .net, directx, directshow, slimdx

I was trying to convert and run the VMR9Allocator sample for DirectShow .NET with SlimDX instead of MDX. I got an exception when it reach this line

```
return vmrSurfaceAllocatorNotify.SetD3DDevice(unmanagedDevice, hMonitor)
```

In the AdviseNotify method in Allocator.cs.

The exception is

> No such interface supported

, and the hr return was

> 0x80004002

.

The sample runs fine with MDX, and my SlimDx is also working, as I've written another 3d apps using it, working fine.

I can't seems to find out what went wrong, no help from googling as well. Apparently not much ppl uses this combination, and non that i can find actually stumble into this problem.

NOTE: I've asked the same question over at gamedev.net 2 weeks back, no answer thus far.

Comment: I have also this problem and don't understand why the question has been close.... Can you reopen it? Turning the Debug Runtime to Retail is not a acceptable solution for me...

Comment: @tinmaru Well, I seriously doubt there's an solution to this, as there wasn't many developers who are active in DirectX + SlimDX combo. Anyway, I'll just reopen it, who knows. P/S: It needs 4 more votes to reopen this question.

Comment: @tinmaru In case you're interested http://www.gamedev.net/topic/514470-slimdx-vmr9allocator-directshow-net--slimdx/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I reproduced the problem with a C++ version and the solution was not defining the D3D_DEBUG_INFO in the program. The problem is that it is not possible to undefine a symbol in SlimDX...

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem myself. It's caused by using Debug Runtime of DirectX. Switching to Retail Runtime doesn't provoke the error. Another Microsoft Gotcha

Comment: as I said in my other comment, there is a known bug in DirectShow. It can work with debug mode but you have to undefine D3D_DEBUG_INFO.